# Why is Npm modifying package-lock.json?

Tags: npm

I’ve got the lock file under Git. After performing several Npm commands, the lock file gets modified - a bunch of new packages get added to it. The commands are:

- `npm config -g set ...`
- `npm install -g ...`
- `npm run test`

That’s it. No new packages are added to the project, `package.json` is untouched.  Why would the lock file change please?

Comment: What version is the lockfile (before modifications) and what version of npm are you running?